# Disable Windows/IIS from restoring older version of website\bin DLL?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I am having a heck of a time getting files updated on an in-house testing web server.  I've updated the DLL for my web app at least twice now... but I'm not seeing the app behavior I'm expecting.  When I look at the file's datestamp in Windows Explorer, it appears to have been updated today/just now.  But when I look in the command line, the same DLL is 5 days old.  Someone is lying to me!

Also had similar issues where I *know* I updated a .config file... and then a couple days later it appears to have been reverted.

Is there some Windows file protection service running here?  How can I disable it?  Operating system is Windows Server 2008 x64.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that the file is being restored, but I would also ask that when you copy the new dll, I would make sure that IIS is not running so nothing could be cached.

To remove a file from Windows Resource Protection, formally called Windows File Protection, is now much more difficult.

Under XP it was as simple as doing the following:
 1. Remove any file you want excluded from %windir%\system32\dllcache.
 2. Then you have to edit %windir%\system32\restore\filelist.xml

Now only certain programs can do it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382540(v=vs.85).aspx

I found a link to a guy, who wrote his own API to do it, but at this point it is no longer routine.

WRP will not make a .config file revert. I would make sure that I make any changes while IIS is not running and test to see if the config holds.

Comment: This definitely doesn't happen on our live server when I updated it... same OS version, so far as I can tell.  Is there not some Windows service I can disable?

Comment: Officially, there is no way to disable it. There is a way by changing a registry entry (easy part) AND editing the DLL using a hex editor (the hard part) that used to work with XP. http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/790/ The problem is that the edits listed there for XP do not match up to the current DLL. You also risk your computer not booting.

Comment: The OP is talking about a DLL for his web app, ASP.NET directories are not under "Windows File Protection", so this muct be a different issue.